# Capturing response to a text or excel file in soapui

Tags: soapui, data-driven-tests

I am using free soap-ui version . 
for basic Add operation(Calculator WSDL) , i am feeding inputs from a text file using groovy and i want to save its response .

Groovy script which I am using is:

```
nextLine=context.fileReader.readLine()
def inputFileResponse = new File("D://file.txt")
if(nextLine!=null){
String[] inpData=nextLine.split(",")
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue("num1",inpData[0])
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue("num2",inpData[1])
inputFileResponse.write(context.testCase.testSteps["Add - Request 1"].getProperty("response").value)
testRunner.gotoStep(0)               
}
```

Problem Area:

1.Now this is giving me complete xml Response . But I just want to get nodevalue "AddResult" and I want to save it in a file .

2. out of 4 inputs it is only capturing the response of last input .I want to capture every response .

Answer (score 0):

For your question 1/ Here is a snippet to retrieve in groovy a xmlNode.
`context.expand( '${Add - Request 1#Response#//*AddResult/text()}' )`.
If you have many fields named AddResult in your response, you need to fill the full path to you node.

For your question 2, sorry i didn't understand well. you say that only the last response is writed to your file ? Maybe it's due to your `write` command that will erase the content of your file. Instead you can use : `inputFileResponse.append("Your response text" + System.getProperty("line.separator"))`

Comment: 1) def response = context.expand( '${Add - Request 1#Response#//*AddResult/text()}' )
inputFileResponse.append(response)   , I tried it like this , but it is capturing nothing .

Comment: 2) Thankyou , it worked out , but there is one problem , I have used ** if(nextLine!=null) for looping(as it is reading data from a text file row by row) ** ,due to which it is **not writing last response** , so which condition should I write so that it captures last response also.